# Properties editor Ui to use in swt/jface application

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, jface, windowbuilder

I am currently working on a project where i have a need to integrate/build a properties editor (like Jboss tools properties editor open in eclipse for editing hibernate configuration files) in my desktop application. I was looking for some good ready to use UI plugin to just integrate in my application or with small changes in the source code of the plugin to make that working according to my needs. Can someone please redirect me to the right way.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a good SWT wrapper, which has provided some ready to use widgets, PropertyTable is one of them.

https://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/opal/wiki/PropertyTable

Hope this will help others.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at http://www.eclipse.org/sapphire/

In the past, I was using [Eclipse Structured Source Editing framework](http://eclipse.org/webtools/sse/). It gives you extensible XML source editor (e.g. you get most source editor features like syntax highlight, code completion - but you can extend and customize those features) - and you can create an Eclipse Forms-based visual editor that would use the SSE XML DOM as a model (e.g. you may add listeners to DOM nodes - to keep your visual editor in sync with the modifications user makes to the source code.

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate configuration files are xml so you should be able to edit them with the standalone Eclipse IDE. When creating a Hibernate Configuration file you would just save it as configuration.cfg.xml and for hibernate class mapping files you would do className.hbm.xml.

I wouldn't say you would need a plugin to create and edit hibernate configuration files. Hibernate will know what to do with the file when it runs as long as they are in the correct build path.

I hope this helps or at least points you in the right direction.